# java entity not removed

Tags: java, entity

i just started programming in java and i am making a very simple game.
in the game you can move left and right and shoot enemies with missiles.
the point is, if an missile hits an enemy, the enemy gets removed, but not the missile.
and that shouldn't happen....
so, here's the code:

---

missile file:

```
public class Missile  extends Entity {

public Missile(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}

public void update() {
    y -= 3;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getMissileImg(), x, y, null);
}

public Image getMissileImg() {
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Vincent/Desktop/Shizzle/Eclipse/Werkruimte/Resources/Sprites/Player/missile.jpg");
    return ic.getImage();
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, getMissileImg().getWidth(null), getMissileImg().getHeight(null));
}
```

}

---

and the enemy file:

```
package game_2;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Enemy extends Entity{

public Enemy(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
}

public void update() {
    y += 1;
    checkCollisions();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getEnemyImg(), x, y, null);
    //g2d.draw(getBounds());
}

public Image getEnemyImg() {
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Vincent/Desktop/Shizzle/Eclipse/Werkruimte/Resources/Sprites/Player/stickman.jpg");
    return ic.getImage();
}

public void checkCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < GameFrame.getMissileList().size(); i++){
        Missile m = GameFrame.getMissileList().get(i);

        if (getBounds().intersects(m.getBounds())) {
            GameFrame.removeEnemy(this);
            GameFrame.removeMissile(m);
        }
    }
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, getEnemyImg().getWidth(null), getEnemyImg().getHeight(null));
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot see where is `GameFrame.removeMissile`. Also you shouldn't hardcode paths like that...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to override equals and hash code.